# Vaadin Flow on Spring Boot 3.2.0-M3

Tags: spring-boot, jetty, vaadin

I'm testing Vaadin Flow on Spring Boot v.3.2 (-M3).
A BeanCreationException is thrown during startup.

Should I use a different startup configuration? (It works fine on Spring Boot v.3.1)

This is the stack trace of the Exception:

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'vaadinApplicationContextInitializer' defined in class path resource [com/vaadin/flow/spring/VaadinApplicationConfiguration.class]: The underlying ServletContext of VaadinServletContext is null and there is no VaadinServletService to obtain it from.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:608) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-M5.jar:6.1.0-M5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:523) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-M5.jar:6.1.0-M5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-M5.jar:6.1.0-M5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-M5.jar:6.1.0-M5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-M5.jar:6.1.0-M5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-M5.jar:6.1.0-M5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-M5.jar:6.1.0-M5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:939) ~[spring-context-6.1.0-M5.jar:6.1.0-M5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.1.0-M5.jar:6.1.0-M5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.0-M3.jar:3.2.0-M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-3.2.0-M3.jar:3.2.0-M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439) [spring-boot-3.2.0-M3.jar:3.2.0-M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-3.2.0-M3.jar:3.2.0-M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:149) [spring-boot-3.2.0-M3.jar:3.2.0-M3]
    at it.xxx.xxx.Application.main(Application.java:57) [main/:?]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The underlying ServletContext of VaadinServletContext is null and there is no VaadinServletService to obtain it from.
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServletContext.ensureServletContext(VaadinServletContext.java:62) ~[flow-server-24.2.0.beta2.jar:24.2.0.beta2]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServletContext.getAttribute(VaadinServletContext.java:69) ~[flow-server-24.2.0.beta2.jar:24.2.0.beta2]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinContext.getAttribute(VaadinContext.java:58) ~[flow-server-24.2.0.beta2.jar:24.2.0.beta2]
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringLookupInitializer$SpringApplicationContextInit.setApplicationContext(SpringLookupInitializer.java:161) ~[vaadin-spring-24.2.0.beta2.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.invokeAwareInterfaces(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:112) ~[spring-context-6.1.0-M5.jar:6.1.0-M5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:87) ~[spring-context-6.1.0-M5.jar:6.1.0-M5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:421) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-M5.jar:6.1.0-M5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1767) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-M5.jar:6.1.0-M5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-6.1.0-M5.jar:6.1.0-M5]
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: thank you for testing and reporting this problem. 

I tried running [Vaadin Spring starter](https://github.com/vaadin/skeleton-starter-flow-spring) with Spring-Boot 3.2.0-M3 in both dev and prod modes, but couldn't get this error, the app builds and starter fine. 

Tried with Vaadin 24.1.11 and 24.2.0.beta2.

Do you have any customisations in your project ? (custom Vaadin servlet, service, look up implementation)

Comment: Thank you for your test, @MikhailShabarov.
I have a marginal customization for Jetty, only to disable SNI in development mode:
`SecureRequestCustomizer::setSniHostCheck(false)`
I have also implemented VaadinServiceInitListener in my project, @Overriding serviceInit.
I get the Exception even if I remove the two mods, though...
What do you mean with "look up implementation"?

Comment: I see, thanks for your reply.
Under "look up" I meant this [API in Flow](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/blob/main/flow-server/src/main/java/com/vaadin/flow/di/Lookup.java), but never mind, looks like it's irrelevant here.
Could you please give us your project which triggers this error (ZIP archive or Github link would work, you can also make a new ticket in [Flow](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/new/choose) and give it there)? (minimal reproducible example)

Comment: I also tried to run the app directly from Intellij IDEA (previously tried with `mvn`) and have no problems.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using Java 21.
@MikhailShabarov, which JVM are you using in Intellij IDEA?

Comment: I used Java 17. Nice comment, let me check it.
Could you by the way try with Vaadin 24.1.11, would you get the same error with it?

Comment: Works for me with JDK 21.
Would make sense if you try run the starter project that I mentioned above (from v24.2 branch).

Comment: @MikhailShabarov, thank you a lot for your suggestion.
I started fresh with the starter project, adding back my modifications one by one.
Now it's working again.
It turns out it was a race condition of some sort.
There was a @Bean in my Application class, loading a Registry for the application from the environment.
Apparently, in Jetty 11 it was executed after the Context startup; in Jetty 12 I had to force a `@PostConstruct` to get the proper initialization sequence.
So, Vaadin 24.2 and Spring Boot 3.2 were only the trigger, the real culprit seems to have been my init code on Jetty 12.